# How to make custom Rectangle property work with corresponding struct's properties?

Tags: c#, properties, struct

I have a `Rectangle` property in my class, which I'd like to make accept `Width` and `Height` correctly, and also return them, as if I was dealing with a normal `Rectangle`.

```
Vector2 position;
Rectangle rectangle;
public Rectangle Rect
    {
        get { return rectangle;  }
        set { rectangle = value; position.X = value.X; position.Y = value.Y; }
    }
```

Seems fine, works great. Except for when you want to get or set `Width` or `X` specifically.

How do I make that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the semantics of your class are such that you can be 100% certain that you're never going to care when outsiders adjust `Rect`, just expose it as a field and callers will be able to set its fields directly.  If you cannot make that guarantee, then you might consider offering a method which passes `rectangle` to a callback method:

```
delegate void ActionByRef<T1>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);
delegate void ActionByRef<T1,T2>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);
delegate void ActionByRef<T1,T2,T3>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2, ref T3 p3);
void ActOnRect(ActionByRef<Rectangle> proc)
  { proc(ref rectangle); position.X = value.X; position.Y = value.Y; }
void ActOnRect<TP1>(ActionByRef<Rectangle,TP1> proc, ref TP1 p1)
  { proc(ref rectangle, ref p1); position.X = value.X; position.Y = value.Y; }
void ActOnRect<TP1,TP2>(ActionByRef<Rectangle,TP1> proc, ref TP1 p1, ref TP2 p2)
  { proc(ref rectangle, ref p1, ref p2); position.X = value.X; position.Y = value.Y; }
```

That approach will avoid anyone having to make a copy of `rectangle` just to change one of its members.  Probably not worth it with a 16-byte structure, but maybe worthwhile if a larger structure is necessary.

A third approach would be to simply require your callers to do something like:

```
var r = myThing.Rect;
r.X = 23;
myThing.Rect = r; // Or perhaps myThing.SetRect(R);
```

The final approach I'd suggest would be to follow the pattern of `Control.SetBounds`, which includes an overload that takes the `Rectangle` members as separate parameters, but takes an additional parameter which specifies which parameter or parameters should be copied to the appropriate members of `Bounds`.

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with `Bounds`. Thanks!

Comment: In many cases, that's a good approach.  The callback approach has better semantics, but compilers as yet allow no nice syntax.  Actually, what I'd really like to see would be support for having `Thing.Rect.X` be recognized as part of `Thing`, either by having compilers automatically generate static callbacks with `ref` parameters (whose internal implementation would be as shown above), or else by allowing property names (including indexers) to include dots [so `var r=myThing.Rect` would call the property getter for `Rect`, but `myThing.Rect.X = 3` would call a property setter for...

Comment: ... a property of `myThing` entitled `Rect.X` [if it exists].  Ambiguity would be resolved by saying that a dotted property name would take precedence unless the expression when binding was legal, so `var i=`myThing.Rect.X` would call the property getter for `Rect.X` [if it exists], but `var i=(myThing.Rect).X` would call the property getter for `Rect` (which would copy the entire structure) and then access `X` on that structure.

Comment: I was surprised when I tried putting `public int X { get; set; }` inside `public Rectangle Rect { (here) {get; set;} }` and it didn't work. Seems very C#-like, but not implemented yet, unfortunately.